# Pipe in ceiling behind old light fixture

Tags: electrical, plumbing, pipe, gas

There is a pipe behind the old ceiling fixture.  When I took off the cap air / has came out. Quickly recapped it. Not sure if it was natural gas.. didn't smell bad, but I'm concerned what this could be. It's an old house (1908). Could this be a gas line in the ceiling?

Thanks

[image]T

Comment: What was the fixture, how old is the house, and where on the planet are you?

Comment: Electric bulb light fixture, 1908, California.  I bought a gas testing gadget ant opened it a bit and tested it. It gave off explosive levels of gas so it's a gas line. Best guess is that it was for gas lighting? Weird.

Answer (score 1):

In the early 1900's many houses used natural gas for lighting. Around pittsburgh, Pa. most old houses were piped for this natural gas lighting. Usually by now all that old piping has been disconnected. Find the source of the connection to the gas lighting, disconnect and cap/plug the piping. The house I lived in until I left for the Navy, had this piping that was removed from the gas supply and made safe.